# How do I check if it returns a null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i should check whether there is some values based on this condition. if there is some, then i should do one action or else do a different action.
i work on rails, mysql and xp
this is not working @test.nil? 
suggest me a alternate way
@test=Model.find(:all,:conditions=>"id=@someid")
thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@test.nil?` should work fine. It's probably not working because your find method is wrong. Try this instead:

```
@test = Model.find_by_id(@someid)
```

An alternative syntax is:

```
@test = Mode.find(@someid)
```

—Which will raise a `RecordNotFound` exception if the record doesn't exist.